# AWK print out the mis-matched records from files comparison

Tags: bash, awk, aix

I need your assistance to find the list of unmatched in the Employee.txt from the following examples on AIX 6.x.

Employee.txt

```
1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
3|Garry|Brown|Houston
4|George|Bla|LA
5|Celine|Wood|Atlanta
6|Jody|Ford|Chicago
```

Car.txt

```
100|red|1
110|green|9
120|yellow|2
130|yellow|6
140|red|8
150|white|0

bash-4.3$ awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR { empcar[$1]=$0; next } { if (empcar[$3]) print empcar[$3] "|" $1 "|" $2 > "match.txt"; else print $0 > "no_match.txt" }' Employee.txt Car.txt
110|green|9
140|red|8
150|white|0

match.txt
1|Sam|Smith|Seatle|100|red
2|Barry|Jones|Seatle|120|yellow
6|Jody|Ford|Chicago|130|yellow

no_match.txt
110|green|9
140|red|8
150|white|0

bash-4.3$ awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR { empcar[$1]=$0; next } !($3 in empcar)' employee.txt car.txt produced the same list as in the no_match.txt.
```

However, I want the no_match.txt to be as follows:

```
3|Garry|Brown|Houston
4|George|Bla|LA
5|Celine|Wood|Atlanta
```

In other words, print the row in Employee.txt when does not have employee no. in Car.txt. I couldn’t work out how to reference those unmatched records in the else statement.

I also encountered a lot of unexplained duplicates in the match.txt with my private confidential data that cannot be disclosed.

Many thanks,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> print the row in `Employee.txt` when does not have employee no. in `Car.txt`.

You may use this solution:

```sh
awk -F"|" '
NR == FNR {
   empcar[$3]
   next
}
{
   print > ($1 in empcar ? "match.txt" : "no_match.txt")
}' Car.txt Employee.txt

cat match.txt

1|Sam|Smith|Seatle
2|Barry|Jones|Seatle
6|Jody|Ford|Chicago

cat no_match.txt

3|Garry|Brown|Houston
4|George|Bla|LA
5|Celine|Wood|Atlanta
```

Note that we are processing `Car.txt` as first file and storing all IDs from 3rd field in array `empcar`. Later while processing `Employee.txt` we just redirect output to match or no match based on the condition if `$1` from later file exists in associative array `empcar` or not.

Comment: Yes, anubhava. It works perfectly and I understand your code. It is very simple. Can you think of any possibility that some of the matched records were duplicated and even triplicated? Unfortunately, it is not possible to share my data but the match string is a ~7-8 alphanumeric characters. Thanks so much already.

Comment: If `Employee.txt` has unique records per employee no then there won't be any duplicates.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Comment: Wondering if I could squeeze in the last question on this topic. How to include another condition apart from the employee # match, is to check if the employee is current/Active (new "status" column) in Employee.txt before printing them. Likewise, only include cars with available colors (new "availability" column) in Car.txt. Thanks again.

Comment: @GeorgeJackson: It would be better to post a new question with an example of data so that I can understand it better and answer.